# Redirecting through multiple pages (login --> signup --> login) without losing the next parameter of url from first page in django

Tags: django

I may not have been descriptive in the title but what I want is that for example When a new user opens a page where login is required --> he is redirected to login page with the login url having a next parameter to the previous page.But as he is a new user he chooses to signup by clicking on a link on the login page which takes him to signup page ,now this is where the problem comes - The signup url gets no parameter and once user signs up he is automatically redirected to login page and after he logs in he is redirected to the index page instead of the page where login was required. I have a custom user model and this is my login view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            email=request.POST['email']
            password=request.POST['password']
            user=auth.authenticate(email=email,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                next_page = request.POST['next']
                if next_page != '':
                    return redirect(next_page)
                else:
                    return redirect('/')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Email Password didn't match")
                next = request.POST['next']
                if next != '':
                    login_url = reverse('login')
                    query_string =  urlencode({'next': next})
                    url = '{}?{}'.format(login_url, query_string) # create the url
                    return redirect(url)
                else:
                    return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request,"login.html")
```

And signup view:

```
def signup(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next', '')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            first_name=request.POST['first_name']
            last_name=request.POST['last_name']
            email=request.POST['email']
            mobile=request.POST['mobile']
            password=request.POST['password']
            cpassword=request.POST['cpassword']
            signup_uri = f'/signup?next={next}'

            if password==cpassword:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.info(request,'Email already in use')
                    return redirect(signup_uri)
                elif User.objects.filter(mobile=mobile).exists():
                    messages.info(request,'Mobile Number already in use')
                    return redirect(signup_uri)
                else:
                    user=User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email,password=password,mobile=mobile)
                    user.save();
                    return redirect(f'/login?next={next}')
            else:
                messages.info(request,'Passwords not matching')
                return redirect('signup_uri')
        
        else:
            return render(request,'signup.html')
```

So what I am wanting is that : The next paramter in login url is taken to the signup url and then taken back to the login url from where after logging in the user can be redirected to that next page. I have been trying to find this out from a long time now but I wasnt able to find any solution so any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by passing **`next`** to your *signup view* as a querystring parameter.

First, you'll need to add **`next`** to the signup link in your `login.html` template, which looks like this in my case:

```
<div>
Don't have an account?<a href="{% url 'signup' %}?next={{ next }}"> Sign Up</a>
</div>
```

Then, make sure you are passing **`next`** as context to your template in your `login_view`:

```
def login_view(request):

    ...

    else:
        next = request.GET.get('next', '')
    render(request, 'login.html', {'next': next})
```

Now in your `signup_view`, simply pass the **`next`** parameter in with your redirects:

```
def signup_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next', '')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(next)

    if request.method != "POST":
        return render(request, 'signup.html')

    first_name=request.POST['first_name']
    email=request.POST['email']
    password=request.POST['password']
    cpassword=request.POST['cpassword']

    signup_uri = f'signup?next={next}'

    if password != cpassword:
        messages.info(request,'Passwords not matching')
        return redirect(signup_uri)

    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        messages.info(request,'Email already in use')
        return redirect(signup_uri)
    else:
        user=User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,email=email,password=password)
        user.save();
        return redirect(f'/login?next={next}')
```

Comment: What happens on passing next in context in login view?

Comment: I have updated my signup view in the question. The issue I am facing is that when I `print(next)` just under `def signup` after request.GET it prints what I need correctly but this next does not show in signup_uri as well as `f'/login?next={next}'`

Comment: @VATSALJAIN first off, you shouldn't pass a string to redirect.  So the line: `return redirect('signup_uri')` should be: `return redirect(signup_uri)`

Comment: @VATSALJAIN also, what happens when you `print(redirect_uri)` ?

Answer (score -1):

I assume that there is a signup link (eg `/signup`) in your `login.html` template. All you need to do, is to read the value of next query param which you got in your `login` view and pass it to your `login.html` template as [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context) so that you can make a signup link like `/signup?next=next_value`. Then, the value of `next` query param can be read inside the signup view and in case user creation succeeds we can modify the code as below:

```
# User has been created
if next_value:
    return redirect(next_value)
else:
   return redirect('/login/')
```

Comment: But in my site it is mandatory for a user to login after signing up so after signup he should be redirected to login page and from there to the product view page

Comment: you can redirect to /login?next=next_value and it should be fine